# Use jQuery to capture checkbox array from one of many identical forms

Tags: jquery

Ok the title needs work but I was having a hard time trying to keep it small

I have a form which gets populated from a while loop in mysql so the form ends up getting duplicated along with all the `class=`'s and `id=`'s. I know that duplicate `id=`'s are bad practice but I don't need them since I can use the classes to accomplish what I need.

Right now with the jquery I have and using `.find('.classname').val()` I am able to get the values from the input fields from a particular form when I click the edit or delete button. That part works fine.

Where I am having an issue is how to grab the `grouptype[]` array generated from the checkboxe's and get that into the AJAX call and on top of that I need only the array from that particular form clicked. I have tried many different ways from examples I have found on the net and none work. I thought I could simply apply `.find()` to the example below, but that does not work.

**EXAMPLE OF WHAT I TRIED...of many**

`var grouptype = $('input[name="grouptype[]"]').find('.grouptype').val();`

Is this something I can accomplish with jquery?

**JQUERY**

```
$("Form#loginForm").submit(function() {
var username = $(this).find('.username').val();
var password = $(this).find('.password').val();
var grouptype = $('input[name="grouptype[]"]').find('.grouptype').val();
var submitthis = $(this).find('.submitthis').val();
alert(grouptype);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/editremoveuser.php?",
        data:({username: username, password: password, grouptype: grouptype, submitthis: submitthis}),
        success: function(data) {
            $('div.alert1').fadeIn();
            $('div.alert1').html(data);
            $('div.alert1').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?> <-- mysql while loop
    <form id="loginForm" action="/to/this/script.php">
        <input class="username" type="text" name="username" />
        <input class="password" type="text" name="password" />
        <input class="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        <input class="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
        <input class="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
        <input class="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="4" />
        <input class="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="5" />
        <input class="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="6" />
        <input class="submitthis" type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
        <input class="submitthis" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit" />
    </form>
<? }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call find() on the form that is submitted, just like you did when you tried to pull username and password:

```
var grouptype = $(this).find('input[name="grouptype[]"]');
```

Then populate an array with the values of the checkboxes that were checked:

```
var grouptypedata = [];
grouptype.each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        grouptypedata.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Then set the ajax data to the array as follows:

```
grouptype: grouptypedata
```

When processing the posted data in PHP, $_POST['grouptype'] will contain a simple array of the checked values, through which you can iterate like this:

```
foreach($_POST['grouptype'] as $g) {
    echo '<div>' . $g . '</div>'; // Do something with each value
}
```

Lastly, change the form's ID to a class, since you're not using the ID and a class will do what we need it to do.  Then you would also change the selector in the jQuery submit() event handler to 'form.loginForm'.

**JavaScript**

```
$("form.loginForm").submit(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = $(this).find('.username').val();
    var password = $(this).find('.password').val();
    var grouptype = $(this).find('input[name="grouptype[]"]');

    // Build array of selected grouptype values
    var grouptypedata = [];
    grouptype.each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            grouptypedata.push($(this).val());
            console.log($(this).val() + ' selected'); // Debugging
        }
    });

    var submitthis = $(this).find('.submitthis').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "postcheckboxarray.php",
        data: ({
            username: username,
            password: password,
            grouptype: grouptypedata,
            submitthis: submitthis
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#output').append(data);
            //$('div.alert1').fadeIn();
            //$('div.alert1').html(data);
            //$('div.alert1').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**PHP/HTML**

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?> <-- mysql while loop
<form class="loginForm" action="/to/this/script.php">
        <input class="username" type="text" name="username" />
        <input class="password" type="text" name="password" />
        <input class="grouptype" id="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        <input class="grouptype" id="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
        <input class="grouptype" id="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
        <input class="grouptype" id="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="4" />
        <input class="grouptype" id="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="5" />
        <input class="grouptype" id="grouptype" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="6" />
        <input class="submitthis" type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
        <input class="submitthis" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit" />
    </form>
<? }
```

**Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/uwmvzzud/

Comment: does not seem to be working, I am getting my data like this instead of serialized `grouptype%5B%5D=1&grouptype%5B%5D=3&grouptype%5B%5D=2`

Comment: I have revised the answer to load the checked values into an array.  See the revised JavaScript, as well as some sample PHP showing how you would iterate through the received array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the id for 'loginForm' on your page.  Instead, use something like the attribute data-loginForm and test for that attribute instead.  Optimistically, document.getElementById (which jQuery uses) will only get your first element tagged with the ID.

Try this:

```
<form data-loginForm action="/to/this/script.php">
```

And in your jQuery:

```
$("form[data-loginForm]").submit(function()  ...
```